# Kibana Search Analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We store multiple language in elastic-search and currently using Kibana as a dashboard.

The problem comes when we search language other than english, the question is how can we specify search analyzer with Kibana?

Answer (score -1):

The analyzers are set in Elasticsearch as a mapping for your index ([see doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html)). Elasticsearch relies on lucene and supports a wide range of languages:

> arabic, armenian, basque, brazilian, bulgarian, catalan, chinese, cjk, czech, danish, dutch, english, finnish, french, galician, german, greek, hindi, hungarian, indonesian, italian, norwegian, persian, portuguese, romanian, russian, spanish, swedish, turkish, thai

Once the analyzer is setup correctly for the fields that you want to search for, queries in Kibana will work as expected. It is not possible to specify the analyzer to use in Kibana since analysis happens when the documents are indexed.